# Conditional expression for excluding equation from GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I am using GAMS, and have defined two sets in the following way:

```
Sets
      i        index
     /a    
      b   
      C    
      d    /

j 
/h 
k
/
```

I now wish to declare a variable of dimension (i,j) as X(i,j):

```
Variables

X(i,j);
```

However, I do not wish that the equation list include the specific i value of d and j value of k. Essentially, I would like it to de-select EQX("d,"k") **only**, while keeping all the other equations for each combination of i and j.

I would normally type:

```
Equations
EQX(i,j) ;

EQX(i,j)$ (not sameAs(i,"d") and not sameAs(j, "k"))..
```

However, in stead of de-selecting that EQ, the script de-selects *all* equations. Is there something off with my syntax?

Comment: What you posted should generate an error, since j is not controlled for EQX(i). How do you want to exclude a specific j, if nothing is generated for j?

Comment: @Lutz Thanks for that- oversight on my part. Thanks.

Comment: OK, that looks better now. But what do you actually mean by "However, this does not seem to be doing what I want it to do"? It would be helpful, if you could provide details about what it does compared to your expectations.

Comment: @Lutz Thank yo u so much. I have made the question more detailed since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New reply based on the comments:

You need to makes sure, the you get the order of `and` and `not` right. So, what you want is `$(not (sameAs(i,"d") and sameAs(j, "k")))` (which is equivalent to `$(not sameAs(i,"d") or not sameAs(j, "k")))` instead of `$(not sameAs(i,"d") and not sameAs(j, "k"))`. So, here is a dummy model using that:

```
Sets  i index / a, b, c, d /
      j       / h, k /;
      
Variables X(i,j), dummy;
Equations EQX(i,j);

EQX(i,j)$(not (sameAs(i,"d") and sameAs(j, "k"))).. X(i,j) =e= dummy;

Model m /EQX/;
Solve m min dummy use lp;
```

And looking at the equation listing, this is the result:

```
---- EQX  =E=  

EQX(a,h)..  X(a,h) - dummy =E= 0 ; (LHS = 0)
     
EQX(a,k)..  X(a,k) - dummy =E= 0 ; (LHS = 0)
     
EQX(b,h)..  X(b,h) - dummy =E= 0 ; (LHS = 0)
     
EQX(b,k)..  X(b,k) - dummy =E= 0 ; (LHS = 0)
     
EQX(c,h)..  X(c,h) - dummy =E= 0 ; (LHS = 0)
     
EQX(c,k)..  X(c,k) - dummy =E= 0 ; (LHS = 0)
     
EQX(d,h)..  X(d,h) - dummy =E= 0 ; (LHS = 0)
```

---

*EDIT: Some details based on a question in the comments*

> The syntax is a bit tricky!! Is there a reason why the order is important here?

Think of it like this:

You are concerned about exactly one element of the couple `(i,j)` and that it `'d'.'k'`. You get this element by writing `sameAs(i,"d") and sameAs(j, "k")`. And since this element should be excluded from the list of all possible elements in `(i,j)`, you need to negate this operation using `not`. For this, you need to keep in mind the order of operations (or operator precedence), which is higher for `not` than it is for `and`, so that you have to use quotes and write `not (sameAs(i,"d") and sameAs(j, "k"))`.

Note that the order of operations is not specific to GAMS, but a general concept in math and programming languages, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Comment: This is precisely what is the issue. The only equation I want dropped is EQ(d,k). For instance, I would want EQ(d,h), equation EQ(c,k), EQ(a,k) and so on. The "and" operator here seems to function as an "or" operator.

Comment: Now I got it! What you want is `not (d and k)` instead of (`not d and not k`). I'll adjust my reply.

Comment: Thank you so much as usual:) Very helpful. The syntax is a bit tricky!! Is there a reason why the order is important here?

Comment: I added some explanation to the end of my reply. Hope that helps